# Is it possible to access child information from parent in Postgresql Inheritance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating the DB structure for one site and I am using for First time Table Inheritance. I need to know if there is posibility to catch child fields when I am making selection over the main table..
My tables are something as..

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
     action_id integer,
     action_type varchar
);

CREATE TABLE likes (
    somefield char(10)
) INHERITS (actions);
```

Is there option to get "likes.somefield" when I am selecting actions table without using JOINs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is to select from the target tables directly. If you (say) wanted a `NULL` for `somefield` for all non-`likes` records you'd do:

```
SELECT
  action_id, action_type, somefield
FROM ONLY likes
SELECT
  action_id, action_type, null
FROM ONLY actions
UNION ALL
```

but this quickly gets cumbersome as the set of tables grows; you're essentially not using the table inheritance feature. That's what the `FROM ONLY` signifies - use that table only, not any children.